# Using GROUP BY and PARTITION BY together

Tags: mysql, sql, database, partition-by

Here is my first query which returns the result in the image below

I get the "Restaurant Name" , "Customer Name", "Count of orders", & "date" from 3 tables namely "Orders", "Customers" and "Restaurants". Then I group it by the restaurant name, customer name, and date.

```
SELECT R.name AS name_of_r, C.name AS name_of_c, COUNT(O.id) AS Orders, date,
FROM orders O
INNER JOIN restaurants R ON R.id = O.restaurant_id AND R.country = O.country 
INNER JOIN customers C ON C.id = O.customer_id AND C.country = O.country
GROUP BY R.name, C.name, date
```

```
name_of_r       |   name_of_c    |       Orders       |       date
Howdy           | John Almagro   |          1         |     2021-01-07
Howdy           | John Almagro   |          1         |     2021-07-01
Howdy           | Luke Pablo     |          1         |     2021-01-01
Howdy           | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-09-01
JFC             | Monty Tron     |          1         |     2021-01-01
JFC             | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-05-04
JFC             | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-06-01
KFC             | Luke Pablo     |          1         |     2021-01-09
KFC             | Michael Wren   |          1         |     2021-01-01
KFC             | Monty Tron     |          1         |     2021-04-01
KFC             | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-01-01
KFC             | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-03-01
KFC             | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-08-01
Kitchen Cuisine | Luke Pablo     |          1         |     2021-01-05
Kitchen Cuisine | Luke Pablo     |          1         |     2021-04-01
Kitchen Cuisine | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-03-01
Kitchen Cuisine | Steven Smith   |          1         |     2021-06-01
McDonald's      | Arthur Chen    |          1         |     2021-01-01
McDonald's      | Arthur Chen    |          1         |     2021-03-02
McDonald's      | Arthur Chen    |          1         |     2021-05-03
McDonald's      | Arthur Chen    |          1         |     2021-07-01
McDonald's      | Arthur Chen    |          1         |     2021-08-01
McDonald's      | Arthur Chen    |          1         |     2021-09-01
```

Now, what I want to do is partition by "name_of_r" (RESTAURANT NAME) ORDER by "date" and give a row number to each so then I can get the 3rd value of each window.

Actually, this is my sub-query from which I want the customer's name who placed the 3rd order at each restaurant.

I tried doing this adding row_number() and partition by but it didn't work and gave me a syntax error

```sql
SELECT R.name AS name_of_r, C.name AS name_of_c, COUNT(O.id), date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY R.name ORDER BY date) AS row_num
FROM orders O
INNER JOIN restaurants R ON R.id = O.restaurant_id AND R.country = O.country
INNER JOIN customers C ON C.id = O.customer_id AND C.country = O.country
GROUP BY R.name, C.name, date
```

What I want have as a final ouput is the name of the customer who placed the 3rd order at each restaurant. Like the table below:

```
name_of_restaurant       |  name_of_customer_who_placed_the_3rd_order
Howdy                    |      Luke Pablo
JFC                      |      Steven Smith
KFC                      |      Monty Tron
Kitchen Cuisine          |      Steven Smith
McDonald's               |      Arthur Chen
```

I know this becuase I ordered by my first table with date

Comment: Please post data as text not images. Also add the desired output to the question.

Comment: I want to get the customer name who placed the 3rd order for each restaurant.

Comment: Use your 1st query as CTE, add ROW_NUMBER in outer query.

Comment: I want to add the row_number and then use it to get the value against the 3rd row_number for each group. Maybe, I'm making it harder than it is idk.

Comment: Learn to format code, it's terrible to read...

Comment: "who placed the 3rd order for each restaurant." - Three orders in each restaurant at the same time?

Comment: In my table above, there are at least 3 orders for each restaurant, I want the name of the customer with the restaurant name who placed the third order. Something like in the table at the end I just added. If this makes sense, sorry I might be making this more difficult than it is.

Comment: see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need a [HAVING COUNT](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-having.php)

```
SELECT
    R.name AS name_of_r,
    C.name AS name_of_c,
    COUNT(O.id),
    date
  FROM 
    orders O
  INNER JOIN restaurants R ON R.id = O.restaurant_id AND R.country = O.country
  INNER JOIN customers C   ON C.id = O.customer_id   AND C.country = O.country
  GROUP BY R.name, C.name, date
  HAVING COUNT(O.id) >= 3
;
```

PS: But it will work for those who placed the 3rd order on the same day. Otherwise, date must be excluded from the grouping.

**UPDATE:**
*added a request for the selection of every third client in the restaurant.*

```
SELECT name_of_r, name_of_c, date
  FROM (
    SELECT
        R.name AS name_of_r,
        C.name AS name_of_c,
        date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.name ORDER BY date) AS nc
      FROM 
        orders O
      INNER JOIN restaurants R ON R.id = O.restaurant_id AND R.country = O.country
      INNER JOIN customers C   ON C.id = O.customer_id   AND C.country = O.country
  ) t
  WHERE t.nc = 3
;
```

See the [ROW_NUMBER Function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)

Comment: This works, just have to give an alias to the table. Tysm Sergey!

Comment: Danyal Danish, I forgot that an alias is required in MySQL.Corrected. Mark the answer as a solution.